# C++ spawn shell in OS X

Tags: c++, macos, shell, terminal

I'm sorry if something like this has been asked and answered; I've looked around but haven't been able to locate anything.

I'm super-new to C++ and I've created a command-line binary in XCode that gets called from a GUI application. The command-line binary executes a shell script. (Before you say anything, yes, I already realize that it's an unnecessary chain of events, but unfortunately that's the way it's got to be.) So the order of operations is GUI -> binary -> shell script. Everything runs well, except there's no output to speak of. I'd like to some way, some how, spawn a Terminal and have the output of the commands executing in shell script echo to the Terminal. Is that a possibility in C++?

Thanks so much for any assistance!

Comment: Since you state that you are calling the shell script from a GUI, what "Terminal" are you talking off? Off hand, I can't see any Terminal involved...

Comment: Hi Dietmar, sorry for not clarifying. I'm talking about Terminal.app.

Comment: So, what you are saying is you **don't** just want to run the shell script but you want to start the Terminal.app and have it run the shell script. That is, there is a new window with the Terminal.app to appear?

Comment: Hi Dietmar, yes, that would work perfectly! Is that a possibility?

Comment: Yes, of course. ... and it seems chrisaycock already posted a corresponding answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get the Terminal to run `ls` with this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  system("open -a Terminal /bin/ls");
  return 0;
}
```

As for the GUI calling the executable, the normal architecture is to have the executable's core logic in a shared library. That way a GUI and a command-line program can both have the desired functionality just by linking against the library.

Comment: That indeed seems to call the shell script I've written, except for some reason I'm receiving an "LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed for the application Terminal with error -600 for the file /Applications/Utilities/runFirst.sh." I'm not exactly sure why that is; would you have any insight?